# how to make cusor to move forward after transaction was rollback?

Tags: transactions, jms, activemq-classic

I would like to get message from queue based on ActiveMQ, if the message is not expected, i want to rollback the transaction to make the message left

But the problem is that once i rollback that transaction, and try to get next message again from queue, i always get the the first one(which is the message i rollbacked).

so my question is: how to make the cusor of message to move forward when i doing rollback?

the codes like below

```
public void removeMessageFromQuenu(String queueName) throws JMSException {
    String user = this.conf.getProperty("activemq.user");
    String passwd = this.conf.getProperty("activemq.pwd");
    String url = this.conf.getProperty("activemq.url");

    try {

        mq = new ActiveMQFactory(user, passwd, url);
        conn = mq.getConn();
        mq.setTrans(true);
        mq.setAckMode("AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE");


        ses = mq.getSec();
        destination = ses.createQueue(queueName);

        MessageConsumer consumer = ses.createConsumer(destination);
        System.out
                .println("++++++++++++++++ Summary Info For Message Queue ++++++++++++++++");
        while (true) {
            TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
            if (null != message) {
                String branch;
                String build_bit;
                String build_type;
                String build_num;
                String cn_url;
                String kr_url;
                branch = message.getStringProperty("BUILD_SVN_BRANCH");
                build_bit = message.getStringProperty("BUILD_BIT");
                build_type = message.getStringProperty("BUILD_TYPE");
                build_num = message.getStringProperty("BUILD_ID");
                cn_url = message.getStringProperty("BUILD_URLS");
                kr_url = message.getStringProperty("BUILD_URLS_KR");
                String key = branch + "_" + build_bit + "bit_" + build_type;

                if (maxVersionList.containsKey(key)
                        && build_num.equals(maxVersionList.get(key))) {
                    System.out.println("Max version of " + key + ":");
                    System.out.println("ID: " + build_num);
                    System.out.println(cn_url);
                    System.out.println(kr_url);
                    System.out
                            .println("------------------------------------------------------ ");
                    ses.rollback();
                } else {
                    ses.commit();
                }

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ses != null){
            ses.rollback();
            ses.close();}
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
        System.out
        .println("==============================================================================================");
        // System.out.println("Remove Done!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you're specifically asking for without doing something crazy like using a [QueueBrowser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) to go through an enumeration of the messages in the queue. A QueueBrowser doesn't pull the message off the queue and we probably don't want to start on how you'd have to deal with race conditions.

ActiveMQ does have options in their [redelivery policy](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) to do things like delaying redelivery. I'd try and go that route if possible.